# Theme Suggestions for User Page

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I want to create a separate `html.tpl.php` for user pages and user edit pages like `html--user.tpl.php` and `html--user--edit.tpl.php`.

For nodes I have added:

```
if (isset($node) && $node->nid) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__' . $node->type;
}
```

in `template.php`.

Is there a way to do this for user pages as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add template suggestions for entities?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97097/how-to-add-template-suggestions-for-entities)

Comment: To check if you are on a user edit page you could check for `arg(0) == 'user' && arg(2) == 'edit'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this template for the user page: [`user-profile.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7.x)

For the user edit page you can take a look at this page: [Customize the User Edit page in Drupal 7 - an example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/howto/customize-the-user-edit-page-in-drupal-7-an-example).

UPDATE: To add CSS and JS to specific page you can do it like outlined below in a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page) {

  if (request_uri() == 'path') {

    drupal_add_js( // arguments );
    drupal_add_css( // arguments );
  }
}
```